# pl sql how to get the day of the week for oracle db date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have oracle date , I want to translate it to my date , for instance 24.7.2011 is sunday so i want a function to return 1 , for 25.7.2011 I want it to return 2 and so on...

I have been searching the wwb for examples but with no successes please help me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Oracle function for this is TO_DATE with the 'D' format model:

```
SQL> select to_char (date '2011-07-24', 'D') d from dual;

D
-
7
```

As you can see, this returns 7 for Sunday, not 1, when I run it.  The value returned varies according to your NLS settings.  If necessary you could do this to get what you want:

```
SQL> select to_char (date '2011-07-24'+1, 'D') d from dual;

D
-
1
```

More details about Oracle's date format models can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-096CA64F-1DA3-4C49-A18B-ECC7518EE56C)

Answer (score 7):

just you have to write `to_char(your_date_column_name,'D')` it will give the same answer what you have asked

just [click here](http://psoug.org/reference/date_func.html) for more details